# Separating Unicode ligature characters

Tags: java, unicode, character, ascii, ligature

Throughout the vast number of unicode characters, there are some that actually represent more than one character, like the U+FB00 ligature ﬀ for two 'f' characters. Is there any way easy to convert characters like these into multiple single characters?  Preferably something available in the standard Java API, but I can refer to an external library if need be.

Comment: I took the freedom to add the keyword *ligature* to your question. :)

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't sure what they were called. :-)

Comment: not grapheme for fundamental unit?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

U+FB00 is a compatibility character. Normally Unicode doesn't support separate codepoints for ligatures (arguing that it's a layout decision if and when a ligature should be used and should not influence how the data is stored). A *few* of those still exist to allow round-trip conversion compatibility with older encodings that *do* represent ligatures as separate entities.

Luckily, the information which characters the ligature represents **is** present in the [Unicode data file](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) and most capable string handling systems have that data built-in.

In Java, you'll need to use [the `Normalizer` class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) and the [`NFKC`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.Form.html#NFKC) form:

```
String ff ="\uFB00";
String normalized = Normalizer.normalize(ff, Form.NFKC);
System.out.println(ff + " = " + normalized);
```

This will print

```
ﬀ = ff
```

Comment: @nonoitall: NFKD is no panacea: there are plenty of ligatures and other notionally combined forms **it just does not work on at all.** For example, it will not manage to decompose *ß* or *ẞ* to *SS* (even those there is a casefold thither!), nor *Æ* to *AE* or *æ* to *ae*, nor *Œ* to *OE* or *œ* to *oe*. It is also useless for turning *ð* or *đ* into *d* or *ø* into *o*.  For **all** those things, you need the UCA (Unicode Collation Algorithm), **not** NFKD. NFD/NFKD also both have the annoying property of destroying singletons, if this matters to you.

Comment: @tchrist: my understanding is that those decompositions you mention *should* not be done. They are not simply ligatures in the typographical sense, but real separate characters that are used differently! ß *can* be decomposed to ss if necessary (for example if you can only store ASCII), but they are **not** equivalent. The ff Ligature, on the other hand is *only* a typographical ligature.

Comment: @tchrist, how did you apply UCA in java, is there an example of how to break down œ to oe for example?

Answer (score 5):

The process you are talking about is called Normalization and is specified in the [Unicode Normalization Forms](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/tr15-23.html) technical note.

There is a class in the Java SE class library called [`java.text.Normalizer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) which implements this process.  However, you need to read the Unicode document linked above to figure out which of the "normalization forms" you need to use to get the result you want.  It is not straightforward ....

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [java.text.Normalizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html), but I am not really sure if that works for ligatures.