# How to get real character codes from any Text VB.NET or C#?

Tags: character

When I want to type two characters, the system converts it to one code (see: image).
How do I know this for the rest of the characters by VB.NET or C#?

I apologize if I can not explain in English, I have used Google Translator.

[Image for clarification : ا+ل = ﻻ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7L8h1.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Separating Unicode ligature characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171377/separating-unicode-ligature-characters)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "real" ? And depending on your Input Method Editor, this conversion may be purely in rendering. Two C# _code points_ can be rendered as a single _glyph_ on screen.