# Ruby: How to decompose only typographic ligatures from unicode text?

Tags: ruby, unicode, ligature

I am looking for a way to normalize unicode input text which includes typographic ligatures such as

```
# Things to replace, for instance:
U+FB00 (ﬀ): ff
U+FB01 (ﬁ): fi
U+FB02 (ﬂ): fl
U+FB03 (ﬃ): ffi
U+FB04 (ﬄ): ffl
U+FB05 (ﬅ): st
U+FB06 (ﬆ): st
```

I want to **keep** all diacritics, punctuations and other marks which could be decomposed, but aren't typographic ligatures.

For instance, I would like to keep the trademark symbol or the ellipsis mark.

```
# Things to keep, for instance:
U+2122 (™): TM
U+2026 (…): ...
U+2120 (℠): SM
U+2121 (℡): TEL
```

I have searched for a solution and found some related answers:

- https://superuser.com/questions/669130/double-latin-letters-in-unicode-ligatures
- [Separating Unicode ligature characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171377/separating-unicode-ligature-characters)

Is there a Ruby specific way?

Comment: lodash has a similar function called [deburr](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#deburr). It's not what you want, not close, but it might be an inspiration, if you can't find anything in ruby. It's only about 10 SLoC long.

Comment: You could test like this `/[[:upper:]]/.match("\u2120".unicode_normalize(:nfkd))` or `/[[:lower:]]/.match("\ufb02".unicode_normalize(:nfkd))` since SM, TM etc are upper case. Wouldn't work for all though. Or use exclusion lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that as follows.

```
h = { "\uFB00"=>"ff", "\uFB01"=>"fi", "\uFB02"=>"fl", "\uFB03"=>"ffi",
      "\uFB04"=>"ffl", "\uFB05"=>"st",  "\uFB06"=>"st", "\uFB06"=>"st" }
  #=> {"ﬀ"=>"ff", "ﬁ"=>"fi", "ﬂ"=>"fl", "ﬃ"=>"ffi",
  #    "ﬄ"=>"ffl", "ﬅ"=>"st", "ﬆ"=>"st"}
```

```
s = "A ﬀ or ﬀwas ﬁ seen™ ﬂ before ﬃ had ﬄ go ﬅ before ﬆ"
```

```
r = /\b(?:#{h.keys.join('|')})\b/
  #=> /\b(?:ﬀ|ﬁ|ﬂ|ﬃ|ﬄ|ﬅ|ﬆ)\b/
```

```
s.gsub(r, h)
  #=> "A ff or ﬀwas fi seen™ fl before ffi had ffl go st before st"
```

Notice that `"ﬀ"` in `"ﬀwas"` was not matched due to the word boundaries (`\b`) in the regular expression.

Comment: Thanks! I have added my current solution which is ugly due to maintaining the character list.

Answer (score 1):

My current hackish solution:

```rb
  def self.remove_ligatures input

    @@ligature_char_regex ||= /[#{ligature_chars.join('')}]/

    input.gsub(@@ligature_char_regex) { |c|
      c.unicode_normalize(:nfkc)
    }

  end
```

Which works, but relies on the a long list of characters defined manually (see below) and might not be the fastest way when performance is concerned.

```rb
  # Return the list of all characters which decompose 
  # into multiple ascii/accented characters
  #
  # Manually commented out those that are not typographic 
  # ligatures such as Trademark, Medical Doctor, CD
  #
  #  List from: https://superuser.com/questions/669130/double-latin-letters-in-unicode-ligatures
  def self.ligature_chars

    return [
      "\u0132", # (Ĳ): IJ
      "\u0133", # (ĳ): ij
      "\u01C7", # (Ǉ): LJ
      "\u01C8", # (ǈ): Lj
      "\u01C9", # (ǉ): lj
      "\u01CA", # (Ǌ): NJ
      "\u01CB", # (ǋ): Nj
      "\u01CC", # (ǌ): nj
      "\u01F1", # (Ǳ): DZ
      "\u01F2", # (ǲ): Dz
      "\u01F3", # (ǳ): dz
      "\u20A8", # (₨): Rs
      "\u2116", # (№): No
      # "\u2120", # (℠): SM
      # "\u2121", # (℡): TEL
      # "\u2122", # (™): TM
      "\u213B", # (℻): FAX
      "\u2161", # (Ⅱ): II
      "\u2162", # (Ⅲ): III
      "\u2163", # (Ⅳ): IV
      "\u2165", # (Ⅵ): VI
      "\u2166", # (Ⅶ): VII
      "\u2167", # (Ⅷ): VIII
      "\u2168", # (Ⅸ): IX
      "\u216A", # (Ⅺ): XI
      "\u216B", # (Ⅻ): XII
      "\u2171", # (ⅱ): ii
      "\u2172", # (ⅲ): iii
      "\u2173", # (ⅳ): iv
      "\u2175", # (ⅵ): vi
      "\u2176", # (ⅶ): vii
      "\u2177", # (ⅷ): viii
      "\u2178", # (ⅸ): ix
      "\u217A", # (ⅺ): xi
      "\u217B", # (ⅻ): xii
      "\u3250", # (㉐): PTE
      "\u32CC", # (㋌): Hg
      "\u32CD", # (㋍): erg
      "\u32CE", # (㋎): eV
      "\u32CF", # (㋏): LTD
      "\u3371", # (㍱): hPa
      "\u3372", # (㍲): da
      "\u3373", # (㍳): AU
      "\u3374", # (㍴): bar
      "\u3375", # (㍵): oV
      "\u3376", # (㍶): pc
      "\u3377", # (㍷): dm
      "\u337A", # (㍺): IU
      "\u3380", # (㎀): pA
      "\u3381", # (㎁): nA
      "\u3383", # (㎃): mA
      "\u3384", # (㎄): kA
      "\u3385", # (㎅): KB
      "\u3386", # (㎆): MB
      "\u3387", # (㎇): GB
      "\u3388", # (㎈): cal
      "\u3389", # (㎉): kcal
      "\u338A", # (㎊): pF
      "\u338B", # (㎋): nF
      "\u338E", # (㎎): mg
      "\u338F", # (㎏): kg
      "\u3390", # (㎐): Hz
      "\u3391", # (㎑): kHz
      "\u3392", # (㎒): MHz
      "\u3393", # (㎓): GHz
      "\u3394", # (㎔): THz
      "\u3396", # (㎖): ml
      "\u3397", # (㎗): dl
      "\u3398", # (㎘): kl
      "\u3399", # (㎙): fm
      "\u339A", # (㎚): nm
      "\u339C", # (㎜): mm
      "\u339D", # (㎝): cm
      "\u339E", # (㎞): km
      "\u33A9", # (㎩): Pa
      "\u33AA", # (㎪): kPa
      "\u33AB", # (㎫): MPa
      "\u33AC", # (㎬): GPa
      "\u33AD", # (㎭): rad
      "\u33B0", # (㎰): ps
      "\u33B1", # (㎱): ns
      "\u33B3", # (㎳): ms
      "\u33B4", # (㎴): pV
      "\u33B5", # (㎵): nV
      "\u33B7", # (㎷): mV
      "\u33B8", # (㎸): kV
      "\u33B9", # (㎹): MV
      "\u33BA", # (㎺): pW
      "\u33BB", # (㎻): nW
      "\u33BD", # (㎽): mW
      "\u33BE", # (㎾): kW
      "\u33BF", # (㎿): MW
      "\u33C3", # (㏃): Bq
      "\u33C4", # (㏄): cc
      "\u33C5", # (㏅): cd
      "\u33C8", # (㏈): dB
      "\u33C9", # (㏉): Gy
      "\u33CA", # (㏊): ha
      "\u33CB", # (㏋): HP
      "\u33CC", # (㏌): in
      "\u33CD", # (㏍): KK
      "\u33CE", # (㏎): KM
      "\u33CF", # (㏏): kt
      "\u33D0", # (㏐): lm
      "\u33D1", # (㏑): ln
      "\u33D2", # (㏒): log
      "\u33D3", # (㏓): lx
      "\u33D4", # (㏔): mb
      "\u33D5", # (㏕): mil
      "\u33D6", # (㏖): mol
      "\u33D7", # (㏗): PH
      "\u33D9", # (㏙): PPM
      "\u33DA", # (㏚): PR
      "\u33DB", # (㏛): sr
      "\u33DC", # (㏜): Sv
      "\u33DD", # (㏝): Wb
      "\u33FF", # (㏿): gal
      "\uFB00", # (ﬀ): ff
      "\uFB01", # (ﬁ): fi
      "\uFB02", # (ﬂ): fl
      "\uFB03", # (ﬃ): ffi
      "\uFB04", # (ﬄ): ffl
      "\uFB05", # (ﬅ): st
      "\uFB06", # (ﬆ): st
      # "\u1F12D", # (): CD
      # "\u1F12E", # (): WZ
      # "\u1F14A", # (): HV
      # "\u1F14B", # (): MV
      # "\u1F14C", # (): SD
      # "\u1F14D", # (): SS
      # "\u1F14E", # (): PPV
      # "\u1F14F", # (): WC
      # "\u1F16A", # (): MC
      # "\u1F16B", # (): MD
      "\u1F19", #0 (): DJ
      "\u01C4", # (Ǆ): DŽ
      "\u01C5", # (ǅ): Dž
      "\u01C6", # (ǆ): dž
    ]

  end
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of `unicode_normalize`. That appears to be the best way of making the substitutions. Don't you mean `ligature_chars.join('|')`? You might consider writing the body of your method as follows: `regex = /#{ligature_chars.join('|')}/; input.gsub(regex) { |c| c.unicode_normalize(:nfkc) }`.

Comment: I was using square brackets to build a character range `[ﬀﬁﬂﬃﬄﬅﬆ...]`. That's why I didn't need an `|`. I was hoping that this would be faster.